# Disk got corrupted, now asking to initialise in disk manager, possible to recover files?

Tags: data-recovery

Transferring files with a USB to SATA interface caused a hard drive to become corrupted
disk cant be accessed and it makes an intermittent clicking noise.

*edit: know that this adapter has a loose connector and constantly loses connection, not reiable but like others I expected the drive would be able to protect itself from corruption due to a bad connection.
the drive was only making the clicking noise using the USB interface, once I connected it with SATA directly to my windows PC I notice the clicking stopped (seems windows was able to partially correct some issue), Im pretty certain the drive is ok mechanically*

It recognised in disk manager but it is saying the disk needs to be initialised.

Is there any chance some software would be able to recover the data from it?
I have not tried re-initialising yet in case it makes the files unrecoverable.

I found softwares claiming it can, I just want to hear from first hand users which ones actually work.

Comment: Clicking drive is dead drive. Disconnect it immediately. Seek professional data recovery. [Or just discard it & recover to a new drive from your backup].

Comment: Yes, a clicking disk is too untrustworthy to be kept. Just discard it… or seek a professional data recovery (which will use special hardware devices in a clean room) if the data are very very valuable (such a service can be expensive).

Comment: See my edit re:clicking, I noticed the clicking stopped after connecting it directly to PC via SATA. Im almost positive it is not a mechanical issue, it's a relatively new drive and the interface was known to have issues.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as @Tetsujin pointed out, a clicking hard drive usually signals hardware damage (although how a data transfer could trigger that is beyond me). Software recovery usually causes more harm than good in these cases. Even trying to read a damaged drive can cause further damage, as you can't really rely on read operations not accidentally changing something anymore. Disconnecting the drive and seeking professional data recovery services would be your next step.

Recovery software is generally designed for the following instances:

1. In some cases, the partition scheme data was damaged (i.e. the differences between NTFS, FAT, ext, etc.). In these cases, the files still exist, but the computer doesn't know how to read them. In this case, a good program can usually access them as long as nothing was overwritten.
2. In other cases, the entire partitioning table was overwritten. That said, the files should still be intact.
3. If file data itself was overwritten (or certain sectors failed), then the files will be damaged. While some files may be able to be recovered (especially if the damage is limited to certain sectors), you may not be able to get all your files.

In theory, good file recovery software can easily recover from the first two, with a little work (file names and locations may have gotten lost, but the data itself will still be intact). In the third case, mileage may vary, and your program won't be able to get everything back, if any at all. In the case of hardware failure, you should really hope that you put a backup somewhere, as even professional data recovery can only get you so far.

Comment: You missed the most important part - drive is clicking. Don't attempt software recovery on a clicking drive. It needs professional mechanical recovery; taking apart in a clean room [NOT at home]

Comment: "Considering that there is clicking, there is a very real chance that [scenario 4] is the case (although how a data transfer could cause this is beyond me)."

Comment: There is a real danger the OP will attempt the early suggestions first, exacerbating the damage.

Comment: Fair point. I'll revise it.

Comment: Right, I highlighted your point, while still keeping the others just for information on instances where software recovery can help.

Comment: Cool - vote reversed.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Welcome :) BTW, I doubt the transfer *caused* the fail - the fail was about to happen anyway. It was just the point at which the fail was made blindingly apparent for the first time.

Comment: Possibly. Either that or the interface he used did something, like a power surge or something (although that would probably affect an SSD more than a hard drive).

Comment: The drive itself should survive everything up to & including rapid forced disconnect from data & power [the data might not survive, but the drive should]. Some drives even have fall detection to pull the heads out of the way. I think this one's time had just come.

Comment: See my edit re:clicking, I noticed the clicking stopped after connecting it directly to PC via SATA. Im almost positive it is not a mechanical issue, it's a relatively new drive and the interface was known to have issues.

Comment: Well, if you are sure that the drive itself is fine, then one of the three scenarios I posted above should apply. Just note that the files may be missing their names and paths.